# How to add custom keyboard shortcuts in Debian 7

Tags: debian, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome, key-binding, gnome-shell

Have a reasonably recent download of Debian 7. Trying unsuccessfully to set keybindings, specifically `<Super>+t` type stuff for terminal etc like I have in OpenBox elsewhere. Default Gnome desktop installation.

specific version output:

```
root@mine# gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 3.4.2
root@mine# gnome-wm --version
metacity 2.34.3
Copyright (C) 2001-2009 Havoc Pennington, Red Hat, Inc., and others
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
root@mine# wmctrl -m
Name: Mutter
Class: N/A
PID: N/A
Window manager's "showing the desktop" mode: N/A
```

Neither dconf-editor nor gnome desktop keyboard applet allow me to persist any bindings (or change existing for that matter). Dconf-editor wipes my newly updated entry as soon as I hit enter. Keyboard applet allows me to set custom keybindings but they simply don't work.

Can someone tell me from the above whether I have metacity or mutter? I thought it should be mutter. But it doesn't look like the recommended solution for that WM - dconf - works anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Keyboard applet works for me.

Click the + button in the shortcuts tab

Name: Launch Terminal          Command: gnome-terminal

Then you should see: Launch Terminal          disabled

Click "disabled" and press Super+T on you keyboard.